# Orbeon 4.10 - Fill Repeat Repeated Grid from Checkbox

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I want to fill a Repeated grid with value from a checkbox.

User would select multiple items from a checkbox then hit a button to add the required number of rows and set the value of a field in each iteration according to what was checked

I would need something like a foreach checked value : run this code

I'm having a hard time finding documentation about this kind of Xforms. I did find some info about Iterate and Iterator that seems promising but i failed to make that work.

I was able to add the required number of row to my grid but then im not sure how to use  `xf:setvalue` set the value of each row.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think a combination of the `iterate` attribute to create a loop, the `xxf:split()` function to get the selected values as a sequence you can iterate on, and `xf:insert` to create elements will do the trick. See [this example](https://gist.github.com/avernet/c00da27fcb3827dbdda4), which does the following:

[image: Example output]

And here is [an example](https://gist.github.com/avernet/58ce0178ebd3d620ce33) which does the same, but for a form created with Form Builder. In this case, the result is as follows:

[image: Created with Form Builder]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seem to be what I'm looking for but i cant get it to work on my orbeon install. If copy/paste your code it doesn't work. One of the difference i have noticed is that i Use a Repeated grid instant of a normal repeat. could that be enough ? here is what i have : https://gist.github.com/Kevinhebertd/0b78b8b46660a025ba10

Comment: Indeed, it is reasonable to suspect a difference with the repeated grid, even if the logic should be mostly the same. I'll try to reproduce this with your example, and will let you know.

Comment: @KevinHebert And here we go, I've added a link to an example using created with Form Builder, which adds rows a grid. You'll let me know if this works for you!